# Javascript print table with pagebreaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, printing

I am trying to print a table created with PHP to the printer using a JQuery function, but although i tried to insert page breaks the table is not smoothly printed on each page.

Here's the function i use:

```
function PrintNeedsSS() {
    var docprint = window.open("", "_blank"); 
    var oTable = document.getElementById("show_needs_table");
    docprint.document.open(); 
    docprint.document.write('<html><style type="text/css" media= "print">      table {     page-break-inside:auto; position:relative} tr { page-break-before:avoid; page-break-after:auto;position:relative} td{ border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;width:auto;position:relative} thead { display:table-header-group;position:relative } tfoot { display:table-footer-group;positioion:relative} </style><head><title>NEEDS</title>'); 
docprint.document.write('<body><center>');
    docprint.document.write(oTable.parentNode.innerHTML);
    docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); 
    docprint.document.close(); 
    docprint.print();
    docprint.close();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: Added a piece of the table i need to print

```
<table border="1" id="show_needs_table" style="width: 890px;border-collapse:   collapse;border-top: none;cursor: pointer;position: absolute;page-break-inside: avoid">
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: What does "not smoothly printed" mean ?

Comment: I means the table cells do not end when the page ends.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the content of the cells and styles aplied to them?

Comment: Added the style of the table

Comment: Width in pixels and position:absolute may interfere. Any class/style in cell contents?

Comment: Only the style in the Javascript function

Comment: I have reproduced the problem. But only when the cell contents can not flow to allow the table fit the page.

Comment: I don't mind filling more than one pages but i want the cells not to break but end in one page and start with the next cell on the next page.

Comment: I get no cell breaks. Everything in its cell. But only when the text in the cells can rearange itself to allow the table flow.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: If cell contents are your problem, change cell contents.